# Sort SQL query by order of where clause match

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT 
    ProcductCode AS Id, 
    ProductPrice AS Price
FROM 
    Products WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    ProductCode = 'efg' OR ProductCode = 'abc' OR  ProductCode = 'xyz'
```

In the above query the I want to have the returned data in order by `ProductCode` but not the default ascending or descending but rather by the order in which the where clause finds a match.

I don't want

```
ORDER BY ProductCode ASC|DESC;
```

So in the above example if we assume that there is a `ProductCode` entry in the table for all three in the where clause then it should return

```
ID             Price
---------------------
efg            1.00
abc            1.00  
xyz            1.00
```

Is there a way to order by "or" order. Kinda stuck on this. Ideas and/or examples would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `case`.  Your `where` clause is easier to read using `in`:

```
SELECT ProcductCode AS Id, ProductPrice AS Price
FROM Products WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ProductCode IN ('efg', 'abc', 'xyz')
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ProductCode = 'efg' THEN 1
               WHEN ProductCode = 'abc' THEN 2
               WHEN ProductCode = 'xyz' THEN 3
               ELSE 4  -- in case you change the `where`, put them last
          END);
```

By the way, if you wanted, you could do this as:

```
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(','+ProductCode+',',
                   ',efg,abc,xyz,'
                  )
```

Comment: Both of your the solutions work but I am more intrigued by the Charindex instead of the Case. Am I right in my understanding that it is taking each "matched" ProductCode checking its index in the string ",efg,abc,xyz," and returning it in the assending order based on where that ProductCode is found? So in this case char-index 2,6,10. If not then can you explain what is going on if I am wrong. THX

Comment: @user357034 . . . Yes.  That is how this is working.  It uses the delimiters so `'ef'` will not math `'efg'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ProcductCode  = 'efg' THEN 1 
              WHEN ProcductCode  = 'abc' THEN 2
              WHEN ProcductCode  = 'xyz' THEN 3
         END ASC
```

Comment: wow that was a quick down vote may I know the reason please ?

Comment: Dude, before you ask "why the downvote", I'll leave my opinion (it wasn't mine). I think that the question was just an example, and your answer is too specific to that particular query

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, op did use `ProductCode AS ID`, so....anyway, I shouldn't be guessing other people's downvotes

Comment: good point Lamak do you expect me to create another example and explain him with that or is it more convenient to use OP's example ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sir the alias is ID :)

Comment: @M.Ali Actually, I don't expect anything since it wasn't my downvote. But, yes, I think that posting a more flexible answer would be good.